# How to change namespace in moment js?

Tags: javascript, bower, momentjs

I'm trying to change namespace for moment js. The script wrapped `(function (undefined) {...}).call(this);`  I could pass namespace in call, however that breaks bower update compatibility (bower would override my change, and I could forget to keep files in sync). Can you suggest alternative solution?

Documentation suggest to use require.js to pass configuration options.http://momentjs.com/docs/#/use-it/require-js/ It's an additional script that I have to load. Is there alternative to require.js?

moment js has a makeGlobal function:

```
function makeGlobal(shouldDeprecate) {
    /*global ender:false */
    if (typeof ender !== 'undefined') {
        return;
    }
    oldGlobalMoment = globalScope.moment;
    if (shouldDeprecate) {
        globalScope.moment = deprecate(
                'Accessing Moment through the global scope is ' +
                'deprecated, and will be removed in an upcoming ' +
                'release.',
                moment);
    } else {
      globalScope.cplex = {};
        globalScope.cplex.moment = moment;
    }
}
```

I combine and minify js with make. One solution that's not ideal:

```
//moment-init.js
var ender = undefined;
if(typeof moment !== 'undefined'){
    var existingMomentJs = moment;
}
//load moment script
//moment-overrider.js
//updating namespace for moment js - abc namespace
var abc = {};
var ender = undefined;
abc.moment = moment;
if(typeof existingMomentJs !== 'undefined'){
    moment = existingMomentJs;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to do it?

Comment: We have a third party ad unit that overrides global moment. We have no control over it. Ad unit loads without iframe